# Finding address range of process ( C / Windows )

Tags: c

I am trying to inspect Notepad's memory in real time, so I can detect when a specific string is written there.
I guess step 1 would be to find out what is the memory range of that process.
This is what I have until now :

```
int main()
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;
    unsigned char *addr = 0;

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,FALSE,7280);
    VirtualQueryEx(hProcess,addr,&meminfo,sizeof(meminfo));
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

I suppose I need to manipulate meminfo in some way to grab the information from there.
I need to find the full address range so I can iterate trough the addresses and search for the string.

Any help will be much appreciated, I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question but I'm just starting out with C.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRPMdb1YMS8

Comment: Thank you that's everything i need :)

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all allocated, valid memory regions you can use VirtualQueryEx in a while loop like so:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>

DWORD GetProcId(const TCHAR* procName)
{
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
        procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

        if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_tcsicmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))
                {
                    procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));

        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return procId;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD procid = GetProcId("ac_client.exe");

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;
    unsigned char* addr = 0;

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    while (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
    {
        if (mbi.State != MEM_COMMIT || mbi.Protect == PAGE_NOACCESS)
        {
            std::cout << "base : 0x" << std::hex << mbi.BaseAddress << " end : 0x" << std::hex << (uintptr_t)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize << "\n";
        }
        addr += mbi.RegionSize;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProc);
}
```